# Vue.js: How to render multiple dynamic component in a single vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have one component, which registers multiple child components. For different file or role, I need to show different child components. And these components are located in different sections of the component. My current realization is to put multiple `<component>` placeholder definition in the template section, just like below:

```
<component
  v-for="(plugin, index) in shownPlugins.top"
  :key="index"
  :role="role"
  :model="model"
  :type="type"
  :is="plugin"/>
```

The showPlugins is defined as below:

```
shownPlugins: {
  top: [],
  left: [],
  right: [],
  bottom: [],
  center: []
}
```

As you can see, I will have 5 places to put the `<component>` placeholder definition, which make the code redundancy. Is there any better way to realize this ?

Comment: your component could have an attribute with the position and then you simply sort them before rendering

Comment: @HorstJahns Can you give more details of your solution ?